# Org-mode export: Resize Plantuml diagram when exporting to PDF and image gets repeated

Tags: org-mode, org-export, images, pdf

I have a simple `PlantUML` diagram in an `org` file and I want to export the entire document to pdf. The problem is that the diagram is embedded correctly, but the picture takes up an entire page. SECOND, the image gets input twice--so need to remove the extra copy. So I am trying to figure out how to resize the picture.

The code I am using looks like this.

```
#+NAME: classdiagram
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :width 5cm :height 5cm :file try.png
@startuml
Class01 <|-- Class02
@enduml
#+END_SRC
```

But when I create the latex and generate the PDF, the PNG file takes up the entire page. I tried to generate a JPG as well, but still no luck.

I tried a few different ways to get this to work like:

```
#+NAME: classdiagram
#+ATTR_LATEX:  :width 0.6 
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file try.png
@startuml
Class01 <|-- Class02
@enduml
#+END_SRC
```

However, the sticking point seems to be that the `Latex` that is generated looks like this:

```
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{try.png}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{try.png}
\end{center}
```

NOTE: This image gets imported twice, which also needs to be corrected.

Anyone know the right way to fix this and resize the image?

Comment: If you use `package.el` please test with `emacs -Q -f package-initialize` whether you also get the duplicated images. If you don't use `package.el` please test with `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't help with the double rendering, sorry. With your code sample I can't replicate it. It is probably something in your configuration.

Adding a `#+RESULTS` clause the image will be rendered there, instead of directly replacing the `#+BEGIN_SRC` block, and it will accept the `#+ATTR_LATEX` with sizing options:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file try.png
@startuml
Class01 <|-- Class02
@enduml
#+END_SRC

#+ATTR_LATEX: :width 5cm
#+RESULTS:
[[file:try.png]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for "How to correct this", but I know a recommended way to "Resize the images" (as if talking about all of them).

By a quick `C-h-v` you can find the variables below.

```
org-latex-image-default-height: default=""
org-latex-image-default-width:  default="0.9\\linewidth"
```

They fixed the issue for me.
To set them per document, look up the way to set local variables in Org-Mode.

```
* Local Variables :noexport:
# local variables:
# org-latex-image-default-height: "0.6\\textheight"
# org-latex-image-default-width:  ""
# end:
```